# How do I find usages of a method with a params argument such that the argument is not empty?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, parameters, il

I have a method in which its last argument is `params string[]`. I wish to search an assembly and count the number of usages in which the `params` argument is passed with at least one value.

There are several hundreds of calls to this method, most of which do not pass in anything to this last `params` argument, so using something like ReSharper’s Find Usages and counting those usages which do not pass in anything to the `params` argument is not practical.

How would I do this using reflection/disassembly? Or, is there a tool that could do this?

Comment: Do you have the source for the calling code?

Comment: Yes, I have the source for all of the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way:

- Add an overload which doesn't take any parameters.
- Rebuild - the new overload will be used in preference to the `params` one
- Use whatever refactoring tools you normally use to rename the parameterless overload
- Count the calls with a simple "find"
- Discard all the code changes :)

Comment: I was thinking: Just remove the `params` array from the signature of the method (and declare a local variable with the same name and array type). Then check the compile error count you get when you try to build that.